# Fading 2 sounds in Wed Audio API

Tags: web-audio-api

I'm trying to fade out 2 sounds at the same time in the piano app on this page:

http://www.intmath.com/trigonometric-graphs/music-note-frequencies-interactive.php

I'm using the "voices" approach and the exponential fadeout is working fine in single-note mode;

```
   vca.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.001, audioContext.currentTime + 1);  
   oscillator.stop(audioContext.currentTime + 1);
```

However, after choosing "Combined signal: yes" (where you hear a 220 Hz note plus the note played), the above will fade out the non-220 Hz note correctly, but the fundamental A-220 plays at full volume for the whole 1-second duration after key up. It's ugly, especially on small speakers.

I've disabled the fadeout for now in the "combined" case (both sounds just stop immediately, which is better than having one not fade at all.)

This is the function called on key up:

```
function doUp(thisKey, e) {
  if(audioContext) {
     for(i=-1; i<18; i++) {     
        if( typeof(active_voices['key'+i]) != "undefined") {
            active_voices['key'+i].stop();
            delete active_voices['key'+i];  
        }
     }
  }
  audioOn = false;
}
```

I have tried changing the first line of the middle "if" to the following, but it didn't improve things:

```
active_voices['key'+i].stop(audioContext.currentTime + 1);
```

How to fade out 2 voices at the same time?

TIA.

Comment: Where exactly does your fade out get called from the doUp function?

Comment: Thanks for responding. The ".stop()" bit has this 1-second fadeout associated with it:  

vca.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.001, audioContext.currentTime + 1);